# Excel Office 365 - Incorrectly calculating autofill for formulas but not numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to extract the data in every fourth cell. For instance the data I want are in cells A1, A4, A7, A10 etc. When I enter =A1 in cell B1 and =A4 in cell B2 and selecting both cells and then drag down instead of entering =A7 in cell B3 Excel enters =A3 in cell B3 and =A6 in cell B4. B5 and B6 gets filled with =A5 and =A8 respectively. When I enter 1 and 4 in cell B1 and B2 and drag down I get 7, 10, 13 etc. as expected.

I tried disabling and re-enabling fill handle and cell drag and drop but without success. Any ideas as to why this is happening will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Autofill bases its' increase off of its' sample size.

Using autofill of 2 cells will use an increment of 2 cells.

Using autofill of 3 cells will use an increment of 3 cells.

This is because Excel uses offsets. It checks the location in the cell matrix and adds the "distance".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula in B1:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(1+3*(ROW()-1)))
```

When filled down, the inner part of the formula creates the series 1,4,7 etc. and appends them to the letter A.  Those values are text, so INDIRECT() converts the text into a cell reference.